# Is there an easy way to make bifurcating/converging edges in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using relative coordinates in TikZ to draw joined curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/using-relative-coordinates-in-tikz-to-draw-joined-curves)

### The problem

This problem is thematically related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/using-relative-coordinates-in-tikz-to-draw-joined-curves), in fact, I was going to ask roughly the same thing before I discovered it in the similar questions list. Now my problem is setting up a **bifurcating curved edge** such as seen in the **lower loop** of the following diagram (which I have now revised so that it isn't upside down):

[image: a chemical reaction scheme]

You will notice from the code that I am using a secret hidden node between C_ox. and C_red. This is to set up a node with an `inner sep =0pt` to act as the starting point for an edge to the 4e- node, allowing the C_red. to C_ox. loop to visually bifurcate.

### Code

This was achieved with the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage[version=3]{ mhchem   }
\usepackage{ tikz     }
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\def\vdil{-0.0cm};
\def\hdil{0.25cm};
        \node (c0) [] {$C_{ox.}$};
        \node (mid)       [right =of c0,        xshift=-\hdil] {};
        \node (c1)        [right =of mid,       xshift=-\hdil] {$C_{red.}$};
        \draw[<-] (c0) to [bend right =50] (c1);
        \draw[<-] (c1) to [bend right =50] (c0);
        \node (R)         [above =of c0,        yshift=-\vdil] {\ce{2H_{2}O}};
        \node (P)         [above =of c1,        yshift=-\vdil] {\ce{O_{2} + 4H^{+}}};
        \draw[->] (R) to  [bend right  =50] (P);
        \node (upmid)     [below =of mid,       yshift=\vdil+0.375cm,inner sep=0pt] {};
        \node (electrons) [below =of c0,        yshift=\vdil] {\ce{4e^{-}}};
        \node (sink)      [below =of electrons, yshift=\vdil] {sink};
        \draw[->] (upmid)     to [bend right =25] (electrons);
        \draw[->] (electrons) to (sink);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, there's a lot of *fine-tuning* here and the code is somewhat brittle to changes in the node contents and even the typeface. Moreover the bifurcation doesn't appear 100% horizontally symmetric as the bend angle is just a guess, whereas the touching edges of the upper loop are horizontally symmetric by definition.

Is there an easier way to set up a bifurcation like this?

Comment: What about using Frédéric's answer from the question you linked, and just skipping the part of the path you don't want to draw?

Comment: That works - I didn't look closely enough at Frédéric's code - I assumed that the midpoint of his curves acted as control points rather than the curves being two-part. I should probably close this question somehow.

Comment: As that other question works, we _could_ close this one as a duplicate of it.  Alternatively, you could post the code that works as an answer and (after a day or so) accept it (that removes it from the "unanswered" list).